# bank sy dont want to regained back the info by himself from classes even info is well being organized

Tags: java

the method  getchangebalance can't get value from setchangebalance method, the setchangebalance get int value and save it into accountbalance variable, but getchangebalance can receive the value from setchangebalance.

Edited:
CheckBalance.java

```
package atm;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckBalance extends Validation {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public CheckBalance(int i) {
    Validation vd = new Validation();

    System.out.println("RM" + vd.getchangebalance());
    System.out.println("1:menu \n2:Exit");
    String temp = sc.next();
    if (temp.equals("1")) {
        Screen sr = new Screen(i);
    }
    if (temp.equals("2")) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

Validation.java

```
package atm;
public class Validation {

public int[] account = {1231, 1232, 1233, 1234};
public int[] pin = {1231, 1232, 1233, 1234};
private int accountbalance;

public Validation() {
    accountbalance = 0;
}

public void setchangebalance(int accountbalance) {

    this.accountbalance = accountbalance;

}

public int getchangebalance() {
    System.out.print("cuba setchangebalance" + accountbalance);
    return this.accountbalance;
}

public void setbalanceminus(int newminus) {
    accountbalance -= newminus;
}

public int getbalanceminus() {
    return accountbalance;
}

public void setbalanceadd(int newadd) {
    accountbalance += newadd;
}

public int getbalanceadd() {
    return accountbalance;
}
}
```

So, there it is suppose getchangebalance() will store the value after deposit or withdraw, but the value doesn't change.

Comment: What is your question

Comment: This code should behave as expected. Could you add an example of what happens and what you want to happen?

Comment: there no value on accountbalance at getchangebalance() method, but for setchangebalance i got the value from parameter int=4000.. it should be able display value at getchangebalance()

Comment: I think you should present us also the usecase of this class, because this code has no errors.

Comment: I updated the question. @Beri

Comment: `vd.getchangebalance()` will always return zero, because `new Validation()` initializes `accountbalance` to zero, and no method that sets `accountbalance` is ever called. It's still not clear what your actual question is -- please provide a [mcve] showing both what does happen and what you want to have happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `CheckBalance` extends `Validation`, you don't need to create an instance of this class inside of the constructor. So your constructor should look like this:

```
public class CheckBalance extends Validation {

public CheckBalance(int i) {
    System.out.println("RM" + getChangeBalance());
    ...
   }
 ...
}
```

If you will create an instance of Validation inside of the constructor, and not assign it to any property, you will loose it after the constructor will finish it's work.

Secondly you could update your Validation class, as your class really is using 4 methods:

```
public class Validation {

public int[] account = {1231, 1232, 1233, 1234};
public int[] pin = {1231, 1232, 1233, 1234};
private int accountBalance; // because this is a primitive type, default value is 0

public int getAccountBalance () { // get current balance value
    System.out.print("cuba setChangeBalance" + accountBalance);
    return accountBalance;
}

public void setAccountBalance(int value) { // set balance
    this.accountBalance= value;
}

public void minus(int value) { // remove from balance
    accountBalance-= value;
}

public void add(int value) { // add to balance
    accountBalance+= value;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression you don't fully understand how get/set methods work or there is something about this Screen class you use that doesn't work as expected.

May I suggest you add a simple main method to the Validation class so you can test and understand the behaviour of that class first.

Below is an example of such a main method (based on the version of Validation given by Beri but with the print moved out of the get method)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Validation validation = new Validation();
  System.out.println("Balance: " + validation.getAccountBalance());

  validation.setAccountBalance(100);
  System.out.println("Balance: " + validation.getAccountBalance());

  validation.minus(25);
  System.out.println("Balance: " + validation.getAccountBalance());

  validation.add(10);
  System.out.println("Balance: " + validation.getAccountBalance());
}
```